# writing a function node for 'null' input

Tags: node-red

I  have three inputs, AND them using the bool-gate modul. This works OK: the flag shows "TRUE" or "FALSE", and the output passes the payloads only if the condition is "TRUE". I don't know how to realize a function node giving out "1" or "0" to turn a relay on.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

`if (node.status === true);{
return node.status;}`

or

`if (node.status === true);{
msg.payload="1";}
else if(node.status !== true){
msg.payload="0";}`    `

but I haven't found a way to get an '1' if any payload appears at the input (the 'true'-condition from the AND-gate) or to get a '0' if 'null' comes from the AND-gate. I have to say that I am absolutely new in node-RED and JS.

Comment: A boolean can be true or false, It can't be null. So the incoming payload must reflect the fact that it has to contain useful info for discriminating a true condition from a false condition.

Comment: yes, you are right - how to discriminate 'null' and not 'null'?

Comment: You don't have to discriminate null from not null. You have to make sure the incoming payload is containing either True or False.

Comment: It is defined by the Bool-AND-gate I'm using. The payloads are passed to the output, independently if the status is 'true' or not. But there is one checkbox. If checked, the node will output message only if the condition is true. So, if condition is false, the output shows null,
Maybe there are other ways of ANDing conditions, but I don't know how.